# How do I default Visual Studio to C# projects instead of VB.NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 keeps defaulting to VB.NET projects instead of C#, I imported my saved settings from 2008 which defaulted to C# projects which did not resolve the problem..

I always accidentally create VB.NET projects then slap myself in the face as I then proceed to delete the project and recreate a C# version of it.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Import Selected Environment Settings... -> Make selection whether to save current settings -> Select C# under the default setting folder

Edit: Checking in with VS Pro 2019 and this appears to still be the flow.

Comment: Yes, the factory-reset is also (hidden) under Import/Export. Strange place.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that, I have now got C# to appear at the top by importing from "My Settings > Visual C# Development Settings" and unticking everything except for "General Settings > New Project Dialog Preferred Language". It's odd that you can't actually set that setting and can only change it via importing settings though.

Comment: Guess they LOVE their VB.net so much?!?!

Comment: @BerggreenDK there seems to be a fairly large group of VB fans, of which group I am not a member. The ECMA-script conventions that C# (and javascript) use are pleasing to me and in my opinion should be embraced by any serious developer and maybe act as a weeding device for the rest. Is that too harsh?

Comment: If I do this it erases all of my custom color scheme settings and goes back to default, however at least now now with C# as the default. Any way to merge my color scheme with C#? It seems like an either or scenario.

Comment: Nevermind, got it almost as quick as posting - under 'Environment' deselect "Fonts and Colors". This will retain all current color schemes. Recommend scanning other selections as well in case there is a customization you would like to keep, because selecting the "C#" environment essentially takes you back to default for everything.

Comment: Glad to help and if everyone else could pile on with thanks and adulations before this gets marked as protected I'd be obliged.

Comment: Basically, just deselect anything from the tree view when it offers you to reset only specific parts, and then just check "New Project Dialog Preferred Language" under "General".

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio (2008..and hopefuly '10 =x) defaults to whatever you chose as the last project's code language you created. Double check that yours isn't doing this >_< Try creating a new project in C# code, exit that project, and create another one and see what language it defaults to. If so, it will allow to keep your "Web Development Settings" rather that switch your main environment to C#, like the other solution suggests.