# How can I use Visual Studio 2010 for C#?

Tags: visual-studio

I've bought Visual Studio 2010 a while ago for C++ desktop development (Learning mostly, not serious development). Now I'd like to migrate from C++ to C#.

I tried going to import and export settings and changing the default to C# but it's not there. Is C# a different product or should it be there? Upon trying to create a new C# project there's no C# project templates there.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, as per http://stackoverflow.com/faq, "What questions can I ask here?" ... "software tools commonly used by programmers", ergo the question is on topic for Stack Overflow =)

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs, I've seen plenty of questions trying to troubleshoot this IDE. I can't program with it therefore I'm going to a site where programmers go to solve PROBLEMS. It's a problem therefore I'm asking for help so I can PROGRAM. Where else can I take this question?

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote it, just offered a comment... the question surely needs some work.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs, I described my problem to the point, I really don't know what else to write in it

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue the other day. I just followed this post on the same question and it worked for me:

[How do I default Visual Studio to C# projects instead of VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927551/how-do-i-default-visual-studio-to-c-sharp-projects-instead-of-vb-net)

Mike

Comment: Same story. That's the question I followed at first but C# is not listed there, as I said in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the command line and do

```
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

(or you may need to traverse down to the Visual Studio directory)

The next time you start visual studio, you should be able to select the C# Developer recommended settings.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but C# is not listed there, just "General Development Settings", "Project management settings" and "Visual C++ recommended settings"

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio, did you elect to install C# components?

Comment: this should be the problem. I'll reinstall with C# components and get back to you.