# Changing default from vb.net to C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

This is a Visual studio related question.
I have an existing empty mvc project and want to add an empty controller.

This was a mistake from my side but when I add the controller it defaults to it being VB.net as opposed to C#. Is there a way of assuring that the Controller being added is C# and not vb without recreating the whole project?

regards

Comment: You can edit the project file manually to "convert" it to C# (ProjectType GUID, Imports and references), but it's probably easier to recreate the project and re-add the existing files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4927597/1805974 this may be what you are looking for

Comment: Cool, got it right, thanks allot!