# How to set the IDE from C# environment to C++ environment in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, ide

All the while I was doing C# using VS2013.

Tomorrow I would need to attend an intensive C++ training for 4 days. I need to set my VS2013 to become a C++ IDE.

Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: What do you mean "become C++ IDE"? Full editions of VS can debug/edit all types of sources all the time... What exactly you are looking to customize/setup? (The only "C++" setting I know is "keyboard loayout", but I strongly advice *not* to change keyboard shortcuts on short notice as you'll generally hit all wrong shortcuts).

Comment: Same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927551/how-do-i-default-visual-studio-to-c-sharp-projects-instead-of-vb-net).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new shortcut on my desktop and change the `RootSuffix`.  This creates a additional set of settings for Visual Studio.

Set the target of the new shortcut:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /rootSuffix CPP
```

You will then be prompted to setup the IDE again and you can select whatever settings you want.  This will not affect your current settings.  I recommend using a different theme so you can easily tell them apart.

Note that the settings are stored in a different folder in AppData.  The settings for my example instance are at:

```
 C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0CPP
```