# web developer 2010 express trouble with events

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a small application on asp.net but I am getting confuse a bit. When I double click a button of project to give a order what the application should do. But when I double click its appeared the aspx.vb instead of aspx.cs. I want to code the application on aspx.cs. How can i do it?

Comment: Is there a reason on why you are not using Visual Studio 2015? The community edition is free, and allows you to write with both VB and C#.

Comment: My pc don;t pass the system requirements

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927551/how-do-i-default-visual-studio-to-c-sharp-projects-instead-of-vb-net), maybe in web developer there is a similar setting.