# VS17: Where do I change the preferred programming languages?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So here's my question: Where do I change the preferred programming languages as seen on the project creation menu in Visual Studio 2017?
This is set to Visual C# for me but I would like to change this. I was able to set it when installing VS17 and it said it is changeable later, but where do I do this?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I default Visual Studio to C# projects instead of VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927551/how-do-i-default-visual-studio-to-c-sharp-projects-instead-of-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

If you a referring to setting the Default settings for Visual Studio.

- Open `Tools/Import and Export Settings` menu.
- Choose the `Import selected environment settings` radio button and click Next button.
- Export your settings, if you desire, otherwise choose the `No just import new settings...` radio button and click the Next button.
- Choose the default settings for the desired language.

[image]